# Functionality of update vs update-in for non-nested structures

Tags: clojure

I was looking over some [Quil examples](http://quil.info/examples), and noticed that 2 different authors (for the "Hyper" and "Equilibrium" examples) used:

```
(update-in s [:x] + dx vx)
```

instead of simply

```
(update s :x + dx vx)
```

Is there a reason for this? If `s` was a deeply nested structure, ya, it would make sense. In both cases though, the list of keys only has 1 entry, so to me, the 2 snippets above seem equivalent:

```
(let [dx 1
      vx 2
      s {:x 5}]
  (println (update-in s [:x] + dx vx))
  (println (update s :x + dx vx)))

{:x 8}
{:x 8}
```

Except that `update-in` will probably have a little bit more overhead.

The only reason I could think of is if they make the state nested in the future, it will ease the transition. For such a simple example though, this seemed unlikely, especially given there are magic constants everywhere.

Is there any reason to use `update-in` over `update` when the structure isn't nested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use `update-in` for a non-nested structure and `update` is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

If you [look at the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5939), you will see they both use `assoc` under the covers.  There is no reason to prefer one over the other except for style and code clarity, taking nearby and related code into account.

Also, `update` was not added until Clojure 1.7, which may play a role in the choice.

P.S.  If you are ever looking for the missing function `dissoc-in` you can find it [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#map-dissociation).

Comment: (a) Why is dissoc-in relevant at all here? (b) If you're going to suggest using your own library, please indicate clearly that it is your own.